# Unity 2.0: How does it work?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm using Unity and would love to read a good explanation about its internal works - mostly how it builds up objects.

I am aware of this nice MSDN article - [Getting to Know the Unity Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650806.aspx), and it has a great drawing of the proccess, but I'm looking for a more technical and detailed explanation.

Can anyone direct me to such an article? I couldn't find one myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use Reflector and have a peek inside?

Comment: No need to use Reflector. It's open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbifold has a helpful two-part series on Unity & ObjectBuilder, which is a core component of Unity.  The articles are from October 2008, and cover Unity 1.1, but much of the detail here should be applicable to Unity 2.0, as I don't believe that some of the core concepts/implementation have changed in Unity 2.0.

http://visualizationtools.net/default/unity-objectbuilder-part-i/

http://visualizationtools.net/default/unity-objectbuilder-part-ii/

Chris Tavares, developer on the Enterprise Library team, has an article, also from 2008, that goes into some detail on ObjectBuilder.

http://tavaresstudios.com/Blog/post/Deconstructing-ObjectBuilder-What-Is-ObjectBuilder.aspx

Comment: all the URLs are not available now :(

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not aware of a technical article that covers what you are asking for, you can take a look at the [source code](http://unity.codeplex.com/) - it's open source.